# python: plot two bars with the two list values with same x labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Now there are two list value as following:

```
lst1 = [17, 24, 16, 3, 9, 10, 8, 7, 6]
lst2 = [25, 30, 29, 6, 7, 10, 1, 2, 8]
```

and x labels:

```
lst_p =  ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'p7', 'p8', 'p9']
```

I want to plot the bars with lst1 and lst2 with different color based on the same x labels.

The code I tried:

```
width = 0.5
plt.hist((lst1, lst2),label = ("data1", "data2")) # A bar chart
plt.legend()
plt.xticks(lst_p)
```

but there is error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seq'

Comment: it is different and there is error use the same code: TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U2') dtype('<U2') dtype('<U2')

Comment: How is it different? The first answer to the question shows you how to generate two histograms in one plot -- isn't this what you want?

Comment: I think it is different. The x labels in my question a str list, not numbers. also the Y is value of two list values.

Comment: @ThomasKühn: The OP wants a barchart instead of a Histogram. There is a duplicate somewhere. The duplicate I marked is I think exactly what OP wants

Comment: @Bazingaa Oh, I see. I got confused by the use of `plt.hist` then. How should I best handle this? If I retract my closing vote, I cant re-vote for this to be a duplicate...

Comment: @ThomasKühn: It's ok, the OP can decide which dupe answers the problem best. No issues :)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [`xticks()` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) the firsts argument are the tick locations. The labels are only the second argument. So you have to pass also the xtick locations to the function call and it works

```
plt.xticks(plt.gca().get_xaxis().get_ticklocs(), lst_p)
```

[image]

Comment: p1 is wrong and I have updated my question

Comment: What is wrong with `p1`? Position? If so, at what position should `p1` be?

Comment: The Y is value of lst1, lst2. p1 have two hist value is 17 and 25.